# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'PayRoll' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_EmployeeNumber'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some problem with the table called `HoursandEarnings` and I kept getting an error saying,

> "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'PayRoll' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'fk_EmployeeNumber'"

```
create table Address
(
PostalCode nvarchar(6) not null,
Address nvarchar(50) not null,
City nvarchar(30) not null,
Province nvarchar(30) not null,
constraint pk_postalcode primary key(PostalCode)
)

create table Payperiod
(
StartDate DateTime not null,
EndDate DateTime not null,
constraint pk_StartDate primary key(StartDate)
)


create table PayRoll
(
EmployeeNumber nvarchar(30) not null,
StartDate DateTime not null
constraint fk_StartDate references Payperiod(StartDate),
PostalCode nvarchar(6) not null
constraint fk_PostalCode references Address(PostalCode),
Department nvarchar(50) not null,
TotalEarningsCurrent decimal(5,2) not null,
TotalEarningsYearToDate decimal(5,2) not null,
Netpay decimal(5,2) not null,
EmployeeName nvarchar(30) not null,
constraint pk_PayRoll primary key(EmployeeNumber,StartDate)
)


create table HoursandEarnings
(
EmployeeNumber nvarchar(30) not null
constraint fk_EmployeeNumber references PayRoll(EmployeeNumber),
StartDate DateTime not null
constraint fk_StartDate references Payperiod(StartDate),
HoursAndEarningsDescription nvarchar(50) not null, 
HoursandEarningsCurrent decimal(5,2) not null,
HoursandEarningsYearToDate decimal(5,2) not null,
constraint pk_HoursandEarnings primary 
key clustered(EmployeeNumber,StartDate,HoursAndEarningsDescription)
)




create table EmployerPaidBenefits
(
EmployeeNumber nvarchar(30) not null
constraint fk_EmployerPaidBenefits_EmployeeNumber references PayRoll(EmployeeNumber),
StartDate DateTime not null
constraint fk_EmployerPaidBenefits_StartDate references Payperiod(StartDate),
EmployerpaidBenefitsDescription nvarchar(50) not null,
EmployerPaidBenefitsCurrent decimal(5,2) not null,
EmployerPaidBenefitsYearToDate decimal(5,2) not null
constraint pk_EmployerPaidBenefits 
primary key(EmployeeNumber,StartDate,EmployerpaidBenefitsDescription)
)

create table Taxesanddeductions
(
EmployeeNumber nvarchar(30) not null,
constraint fk_Taxesanddeductions_EmployeeNumber references PayRoll(EmployeeNumber),
StartDate DateTime not null
constraint fk_Taxesanddeductions_StartDate references Payperiod(StartDate),
TaxesandDeductionsDescription nvarchar(50) not null,
TaxesandDeductionsCurrent decimal(5,2) not null,
EmployerPaidBenefitsYeartoDate decimal(5,2) not null,
constraint pk_Taxesanddeductions 
primary  key(EmployeeNumber,StartDate,TaxesandDeductionsDescription)

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a composite key `(EmployeeNumber,StartDate)` on table `PayRoll`, you will need to reference both keys in the foreign key in the other tables which reference it.

<del>If `EmployeeNumber` is unique in table  `Payroll`, then you can make just `EmployeeNumber` the primary key on `Payroll`, and then your foreign keys on the other 3 tables to `Payroll` will be valid as-is.</del>(Not the case)

Not related, but I believe you may run into problems making `PostalCode` a primary key on `Address` - this will mean that only one address with the same PostalCode may be added to the table. I would suggest a surrogate key instead.

**Edit**

Example of both columns in the foreign key:

```
constraint fk_HE_EmployeeNumber 
   foreign key(EmployeeNumber, StartDate) 
   references PayRoll(EmployeeNumber, StartDate)
```

Note also that primary and foreign key constraint names must be unique within the database (not just in the table) - you'll need to rename the duplicate keys like `fk_StartDate`.

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa5e0)

You may also find at some point that the encumberance and additional storage requirements of composite / compound keys may make implementation of simple surrogate keys (like `int identity()` or Guids) a simpler approach.

Comment: I'm confused, and which part of the table that I'm supposed to changed create table PayRoll since I need to keep the table of payroll like the primary keys of EmployeeNumber,StartDate and the foreign key postalcode. I still don't understand for that table HoursandEarnings to have the reference for primary keys startdate,EmployeeNumber,HoursAndEarningsDescription  and foreign keys like startdate,and employeenumber

Comment: Any time you have `TableA` with primary key with `column1, column2, ...` and wish to add referential integrity from `TableB`, you need to 1) Add ALL columns to `TableB` with the same types, and 2) Add All columns to the foreign key. The [SqlFiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa5e0) shows an example.